# Can the IntelliJ external maven library tell where the dependencies are from?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ and maven for dependencies.
From the External library, I could see the maven import dependencies.

[image]

Something like this, is that possible to know where these dependencies come from?
I try to search for com.sun.xml: jaxb-core in the pom file but I can't find exactly that dependency. So is that possible to know where this single dependency comes from? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Important - this is for ultimate/paid version only (otherwise for maven based project use - `mvn dependency:tree`)

Follow the steps here, I am also attaching the screen shots for better understanding.

1. Open your POM.xml in the editor -> right click in the editor area -> diagrams ->  show dependencies, like below:-

alternatively use shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>

[image]

2. after this a separate window with some hierarchy will show up like below(sorry but for complex dependencies it actually shows up like this):-

[image]

3. there you can search your dependency by typing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and entering the dependency name like `jaxb-core` or anything upto your case, in my case i searched `jackson-core`
4. After little zooming in, you can also click on the line arrows to check where it is coming from and do that until you want to check from which initial dependency is it coming from, refer the image below for this:-

[image]

Comment: It is only in Intellij IDEA Ultimate version. If you are using the Community version like me, `mvn dependency:tree` works fine.

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Sample output for https://github.com/statsbiblioteket/streamtuples:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ streamtuples-integration-test ---
[INFO] dk.kb.stream:streamtuples-integration-test:jar:0.5-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- dk.kb.stream:streamtuples:jar:0.5-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.196:compile
[INFO] +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.1.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.0.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.0.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO] \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]
```